# Password field in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two small problems/questions about app development in Windows Phone 7.

**1:**
I am trying to use a generic password field in Windows Phone 7. When I created a generic regular text field, I could "pole" it's value with the variable username.Text, ("username" being the name of the text input field).

```
MessageBox.Show("Success! Username: "+username.Text+", Password: "+password.Text+".");
```

However, when I try to do the same thing for a password box, it tells me:

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Josha\workspace\App\App\MainPage.xaml.cs   36  93  App

I have tried searching around on the internet for hours, but have not gotten any relevant results.

**Question number 2:**
Does anyone know of a way to put "hint" text in said password box? I would like it to say in grayed-out letters "Password" when it is blank.

Thanks all!

Comment: Question1 is password.Password. Question 2 involves simultaneously using an overlapping TextBox and PasswordBox, detecting GotFocus on the TextBox, and hiding its Visibility, and then calling Focus() on the PasswordBox. (And LostFocus on the PasswordBox to re-'Visible' the TextBox if no input was entered)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for question 1: `pwdName.Password` give the value of the password (pwdName is the x:name of the control)

For question 2: watermarking for password box is possible by creating your custom control or go through [this](http://damianblog.com/2011/01/21/wp7-password-watermark/) article

Comment: Ahh brilliant, the password.Password worked great! Am going to attempt the article linked by Praneeth shortly.

One last question, do you know of a way to set "default" text in the password field? (Not like a watermark, but like a pre-defined password, like if I added a Remember Me feature)

thanks!

Comment: Wait, figured it out! :)
`password.Password = "pass";`